# "Peeving about grammar disguised as a question"

Tags: word-usage

In the FAQ for this site, *peeving about grammar disguised as a question* is discouraged. The various forms of *[peeve](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/peeve)* in Merriam-Webster however does not justify this usage.

*Peeve* is a verb meaning *annoy*, forming *peeved* and *peeving*. It is also a noun meaning *grievance*. [*Peevish*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/peevish) is an adjective meaning *ill-tempered*.

*Peeving about grammar* then would suggest one can rewrite the phrase as *annoying about grammar* which does not make sense. How common then is this usage of *peeving* and is it legitimate?

Comment: Is this peeving about *peeve* disguised as a question?

Comment: Appears like a hasty question. Checking out the different meanings and usage of *peeve* should have resolved.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In fact this usage of the verb *peeve*, which is chiefly American, is old and well documented in the Oxford English Dictionary:

> "...to grumble, complain petulantly..."
>
> **1912** Ade *Knocking Neighbors* 10 The Waiter peeved at being slipped a paltry $1.60.

Answer (score 1):

Whatever the logic, 'peeving' is a noun for 'the act of complaining'. 'Annoying' is simply an adjecting that the modified object annoys something else.

The verb 'to peeve' is rare: 'X peeves Y' sounds strange. The most common usage of the root is as a noun: X is a peeve of Y' translates to 'X annoys Y'. And the noun 'peeving' is most likely a formation directly from that noun rather through the verb form.

Comment: I don't think [It peeves me](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22that+peeves+me%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#sclient=psy-ab&hl=en&tbo=1&tbm=bks&source=hp&q=%22it+peeves+me%22&psj=1&oq=%22it+peeves+me%22&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=4578l6409l0l7102l6l6l0l0l0l0l58l248l6l6l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.,cf.osb&fp=8d41219106f29d66&biw=1305&bih=800) sounds at all strange, though I suspect it may gain some currency by association with *"It piqued me"*.